# How install packages in lazarus headless in solaris

Tags: indy, lazarus, opensolaris, headless

I want to test a lazarus project running in a opensolaris box. I will need to install lazarus+freepascal + indy + remobjects librarys and run everything headless.

I have no clue in how make this happened. As far as I know at looking the docs everything is done with the GUI.

Comment: Reply updated answer with new developments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik there currently are no opensolaris releases due to the lack of a maintainer. Which means : DIY.

There are some minor commits from time to time from Pierre though so it might be close to a general working state.

UPDATED: Free Pascal 2.4.2 has opensolaris packages:

- ftp://ftp.hu.freepascal.org/pub/fpc/dist/2.4.2/i386-solaris/
- ftp://ftp.hu.freepascal.org/pub/fpc/dist/2.4.2/sparc-solaris/

Note that these are considered experimental. We hope they will turn into a full platform over time.